# Issue with my Django request from a JSON POST

Tags: jquery, python, json, django, pymongo

I try to access to a JSON object, sent from JS-jquery with $.post to a Django script,

I tried a combination on many things I saw on Stackoverflow, but I cant make it work :

On the .js side :

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function() {
    var payload = {"name":"Richard","age":"19"};
    $("#console").html("Sending...");
    $.post("/central/python/mongo_brief_write.py",{'data': JSON.stringify(payload)},
                                           function(ret){alert(ret);});
    $("#console").html("Sent.");
});
```

and the content of my script named mongo_brief_write.py is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def save_events_json(request):
    t = request.raw_post_data
    return t

con = Connection("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/")
db = con.central
collection = db.brief
test = {"name":"robert","age":"18"}
post_id = collection.insert(t)

def index(req):
    s= "Done"
return s
```

If I press the submit button, I have the "Done" alert displayed correctly, but nothing in my collection in my mongoDB.

If I replace t by test in

```
post_id = collection.insert(test)
```

I have the done alert too and my object is created in my mongo DB collection.

Where is my mistake ? in my POST request ? I work under Apache and I use modpython.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its happens because of python namespace rules. If you define variable in function:

```
>>>def random_func(input):
       t = input
       return t
>>>t
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

Its won't be global variable.
So, what you need to do is too ways:
first, put code with base manipulation in function save_events_json:

```
def save_events_json(request):
    t = request.raw_post_data
    con = Connection("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/")
    db = con.central
    collection = db.brief
    test = {"name":"robert","age":"18"}
    post_id = collection.insert(t)
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    return HttpResponse(content=t)
```

or set the variable "t" global:

```
def save_events_json(request):
    global t
    t = request.raw_post_data
    return t
```

Comment: Dear @Kyrylo Perevozchikov, thx for your help,
I understand your point with the global var, which make sense, but it didn't solve my problem unfortunately.
What I don't understand is if I remove this part of my .py script : 
    def index(req):
        s= "Done"
        return s, put all the lines in the same save_events_json function with a return t at the end, I  have a POST 500 Internal server error ?

Comment: Dear @Manuhoz, its because you return not HttpResponse object, try to "from django.http import HttpResponse", "return HttpResponse(content=t)"

Comment: I sent more details below to properly format the code thx @Kyrylo Perevozchikov

Answer (score 0):

Dear @Kyrylo Perevozchikov, I've updated my code :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest
request = HttpRequest()
if request.method == 'POST':
    def index(request):
        global t
        t = request.raw_post_data                          
  post_id=Connection("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/").central.brief.insert(t)
        return HttpResponse(content=t)
else:
    def index(req):
        s="Not A POST Request"
        return s
```

When I click on the jquery button I have the "Not A POST Request"